# ClientId missing in application startup (keycloak-js 6.0.1)

Tags: keycloak

Trying to implement keycloak in an ionic project. Followed the instruction given here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cmotion/ionic-keycloak-auth. Getting error `ClientId missing` in the console. KeycloakConfig is given bellow.

```
{
  url: 'http://192.168.1.8:8083/auth/',
  realm: 'MyDemoApp',
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxx',
  credentials: {
    secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
}
```

[image]